# Monospace font sometime loses pixels

Tags: html, css, monospace

I'm trying to implement a html/css/js editor, to make things easier I decided to use a monospace font, in this case the JetBrains font. But as I tried setting the caret position to a multiple of the size of one letter, I noticed that the caret was, when the text got big enough, way further then what I expected.

Playing a bit with this, I figured a really weird thing, here is an example:
[image]

Do you know why this is happening and if there is a way of implementing it like that, or should I always recalculate the width of the whole line?

By the way, here is the css code of the sizer:

```css
.__editor-sizer {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of trials, I finally came up to the conclusion that the issue could only come from the `.clientWidth` property, which appears to convert the result to an int. That is why I tried using `.getBoundingClientRect().width` instead. This is the result, not perfect but enough close for me:

[image]